# Static QGraphicsItem on QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a simple Pacman-clone game in Qt, using the Graphics View Framework. I have create a class, `WallItem`, which inherits QGraphicsItem. It reprsent maze,that consists of many small pieces(arcs,straight lines, etc).

```
class WallItem: public QGraphicsItem
{
protected:
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
}
```

Main class of my application inherits QGraphicsView.

```
class Canvas:  public QGraphicsView 
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    WallItem* wallItem;
    PacmanItem* pacman;
    //other items
}
```

In constructor of Canvas,I add wallItem to the scene;

```
wallItem = new WallItem(/*params*/);
scene()->addItem(wallItem);
pacmanItem = new PacmanItem(/*params*/);
scene()->addItem(pacmanItem);
//other items
```

The problem is that I would like to call method `paint` of wallItem only once - at the beginning of the application,because walls in maze are static. However, when pacman move or food removed, scene updates and ALL items, including wallItem, repainted that affect on perfomance. How I can make my `wallItem` static,without repainting on every update in scene?

Sorry for my English, it's not my first language.

Comment: perhaps QGraphicsItem::ItemCoordinateCache is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[enum QGraphicsItem::CacheMode](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum)

"Caching is used to speed up rendering by allocating and rendering to an off-screen pixel buffer, which can be reused when the item requires redrawing. For some paint devices, the cache is stored directly in graphics memory, which makes rendering very quick."

Try

```
QGraphicsItem::ItemCoordinateCache
```